# Is there a benefit to securing all directories under a parent directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security, chmod

The sysadmins at work want us to remove all world permissions from all files and directories within a specific filesystem. Normally, I would agree with such security practices. However, I don't understand the point in doing so because the parent directory only allows users within a specific group to access the filesystem.

For example, the parent directory has permissions like:

```
drwxr-x--- 5 root group 4096 Apr  7 15:27 /example
```

And the subdirectories have permissions like:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 user group 4096 Apr 10 00:34 /example/dir1
drwxrwxrwx 2 user group 4096 Apr  8 12:52 /example/dir2
drwxrwx--- 2 user group 4096 Apr 12 08:13 /example/dir3
```

Note: `/example/dir1` and `/example/dir2` are what currently exists. `/example/dir3` is what our sysadmins want the permissions to be.

Is there any benefit to removing world permissions from `/example/dir1` and `/example/dir2` when only users in `group` can access this filesystem? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accountability:

If you have the permission like `dir3`, you know quickly that who has access to that file. In the other case, you should go back until you see the correct permission.

Safety:

you may need `dir4` accessible by webbrowser, so you sysadmin need to change also `example`, but now he does not know that are the correct permissions of `dir1` and `dir2`.

In general and the best practice: it is always better to use the minimal permissions, so you know (by seeing additional permissions) what are the additional requirements (it is a sort of lazy boy documentation; but we all tend to be lazy on documentation).

Note: some program could complain (and stop) if they find "world/all" permission: they usually check just current directory permission (why do complex checks? and with volumes mounted multiple time, it could be difficult (and not portable) to find possible attacks)

Comment: Good answer. Your examples for accountability and safety make sense. Thanks!